# Where does Docker store the content of running containers?

Tags: docker, filesystems, directory-browsing

Is there a way to browse the files that were created within a running container?

Say I'm starting a container using

```
sudo docker run --name myContainer -d ubuntu
```

Which has the ID `eefea5f7df52e8c1aad24b4068564237021dc7b953026f0adb696878a3d25f72`

I thought there is a folder created (with the name of the container-ID) somewhere in `/var/lib/docker/` containing the files that where created,...

I found a couple of folders in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff` (so of them are also deleted when removing containers), but I have no idea how to map them the container IDs.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you'd want to know this, but it is possible.

Using `docker inspect`, you can find out more about the internals of a container. Try issuing `docker inspect eefea5f7df52e8c1aad24b4068564237021dc7b953026f0adb696878a3d25f72` to see a full tree of information about a container.

I believe `docker inspect --format='{{.GraphDriver.Data.LowerDir}}' eefea5f7df52e8c1aad24b4068564237021dc7b953026f0adb696878a3d25f72` gives you the path to where your container data is stored. You'll need root access to open that folder though, with good reason as it is not a good idea to try and alter data there!